# JPARepository Interface

Tags: java, interface, spring-data-jpa

I've learned from several examples that by extending JPARepository interface, you get access to the most often used CRUD operations. So you avoid boilerplate coding. This is great, but I am struggling to understand how it works for as far as I know from Java basics, interfaces do not provide ready-to use implementations. Interfaces are meant for implementing methods declared in them. How it turns out that by implementing interface we get access to ready to use functionality? Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Interfaces are just that: interfaces. They're thin contracts that have no functionality. You have to implement the functionality yourself. If you are inheriting from a class however, then you are inheriting all of the class's functionality as long the functions are scoped to the child. In C# the inherited child scopes are `public` and `protected`, not sure what they are in Java. This is a very broad question and you might need to do some more research.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that Spring data makes use of something called the JDK dynamic proxy.

What happens is Spring Data intercepts calls to the interface that extends one of the Spring data repositories and forwards those calls to SimpleJpaRepository which is used as the implementation.